# Comparing to null with "<>"

Tags: operators

I was reviewing some Apex code when I found an expression like this:

```
if (a <> null && b != null) {
  ...
}
```

My gut feeling tells me that `<>` is an alternative way to say "not equals," is this correct? If so, is it different than `!=`, sort of like how `!=` and `!==` are similar yet different?

I could not find any references to `<>` in the following documentation:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_precedence.htm

Comment: Poll Response: I always use !=

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct that it isn't in the docs. The operators are identical in operation.

`<>` is from the days of BASIC and `!=` is from the days of C and is used by the languages that followed it. Most modern languages support both.

Wikipedia: [Relational Operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator#Standard_relational_operators)

Comment: Thanks. I know SQL uses `<>` too and it means the same thing. But I was not sure being a new language (to me).